# Not able to return proper json response

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a php script in which i have the following function :

```
<?php
function readXML() {
    $url = $_REQUEST['schemaPath'];

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $fields = $xml -> fields -> field;
    GLOBAL $array;
    GLOBAL $c;
    $array = new stdClass;
    foreach($fields as $field->attributes){
        foreach($field->attributes->attributes() as $a => $b){
            if($a == "name") {
                $c = $b;
            }
            if($a == "type") {
                $array -> $c = $b;
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($array);
}
echo readXML();
?>
```

I am making ajax call in the following way :

```
$.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "readXML.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
                data: { schemaPath: "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/file/?file=schema.xml" },
                crossDomain: true,
                success:function(data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        alert("Error in processing xml file");
                        return null;
                    } else {                
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                error:function(data) {
                    alert("Error while reading schema file.");
                    $("#loadingStatus").hide();
                }
            });
```

I am not getting the desired json response format. I get the alert `Error while reading schema file` in the response. I actually want it be as a `key:value` pattern like as `$c:$b` but it is coming like `$c:{"0":$b}`. How to return the array from the php script such that i can have a valid json response.

Comment: tip: `$array = new stdClass` is likely to cause confusion. that's an object, not an array. at least use proper descriptive variable names, and not the equivalent of `$cat = 'dog'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution why on completion of ajax call it was always going to the error function. Here i am doing `jsonp` in the ajax call but was not handling the same in the php script. To solve this problem and to return a proper response need to add the following in the php script :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['jsonp'])) {
        echo $_REQUEST['jsonp'].'('.json_encode($array).')';
    }else{  
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

And to make the response as `key:value` need to change the `$array[$c] = $b;` to `$array[$c] = (string)$b;` along with the change pointed by @EmmanuelG in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a stdClass, why not just use a regular associative array. This would fix your issue with the least amount of change.

```
<?php
function readXML() {
    $url = $_REQUEST['schemaPath'];

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $fields = $xml -> fields -> field;
    GLOBAL $array;
    GLOBAL $c;
    $array = array(); // changed
    foreach($fields as $field->attributes){
        foreach($field->attributes->attributes() as $a => $b){
            if($a == "name") {
                $c = $b;
            }
            if($a == "type") {
                // cast the $c to convert the value from a SimpleXMLObject 
                // to a string for use within the key
                $c = (string)$c; 
                $array[$c] = $b;
            }
        }
    }
    return json_encode($array);
}
echo readXML();
?>
```

Comment: This gives the error `Warning: Illegal offset type in readXML.php on line 19` which is `$array[$c] = $b;` in the response.

Comment: Gah! I should have checked that you were iterating through SimpleXML Elements. Whenever you access one, unless the item is an array, the value will be of type SimpleXMLObject. You will need to cast the key ($c) to a string in order to fix this. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am getting the output as `[$c] => SimpleXMLElement Object([0] => $b)` which after json_encode becomes `$c:{"0":$b}`. I want it instead as `$c:$b` which i am not able to do. Also it always comes to the error function.